# Can't get around a simple error in Java

Tags: java

I've just downloaded the JDK, installed JGrasp, and have being trying to write my first Java program(hypotenuse of a triangle).  Here is my program:

```
public class Hypot {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double hypotenuse;
        double d1;
        double d2;

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("You need to enter two arguments!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            d1 = new Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
            d2 = new Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Arguments need to be numbers!");
            System.exit(2);
        }


        hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((d1 * d1) + (d2 * d2));
        System.out.print("The hypotenuse of the right angle triangle with sides of " + d1 + "and" + d2 + "is" + hypotenuse);
    }
}
```

I have being getting these two errors; I don't really understand what they are.

> ```
> Hypot.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>    d1= new Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
>                  ^
>   symbol:   class parseDouble
>   location: class Double
> Hypot.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
>    d2= new Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
>                  ^
>   symbol:   class parseDouble
> ```

Comment: Just remove the `new` from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this statement

```
   d1= new Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
```

is that you are trying to create an instance of primitive double which is returned from `parseDouble`

So during compilation this statement is becoming

```
 d1 = new double;
```

which is syntatically incorrect.

As parseDouble return a double so you can simply assign to your d1 double variable without using `new` operator:

```
d1 = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
```

Also note that, to access `static` variables/methods, you don't have to create an instance of the class. You can access them using the classname, for example : Double.parseDouble(args[0]);

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
  public class Hypot{
   public static void main(String args[])
  { 
   double hypotenuse;
   double d1 = 0.0d;
   double d2 = 0.0d;

   if(args.length!=2)
   {
   System.out.println("You need to enter two arguments!");
   System.exit(1);
   }

   try
   {
   d1= Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
   d2= Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
   {
   System.out.println("Arguments need to be numbers!");
   System.exit(2);
   } 




   hypotenuse=Math.sqrt((d1*d1)+(d2*d2));
   System.out.print("The hypotenuse of the right angle triangle with sides of "+d1+"and"+d2+"is"+hypotenuse);
  }
 }
```

Comment: thanks,I kind of did that ,but then it gives a error that d1 and d2 might not be initialize that why I tried writing the 'new' there,

Comment: @Snedden27 method local variables need to be initialized, hence it throws an error. So while defining them assign a default values    double d1 = 0.0d;

Comment: yeah ,but don't I initialize them when I say,
d1= new Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
   d2= new Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

Answer (score 3):

It's a static method, don't write new. You only use new to instantiate classes. "parseDouble" is not an inner class, so you can't use new. Methods are just called. The "factory pattern" uses static methods to return an instance, which means the static method contains the instantiation (the new).

Answer (score 2):

[Double.parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) is a static method, so you don't have to instantiate `Double` in order to use `parseDouble`.  Having said that if you wanted to call a non-static method that Double has it would look like `new Double(string).doubleValue();`

```
   d1= Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
   d2= Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
```